# rename files with a subfolder name one level up

Tags: python, python-2.7, rename

I have a parent folder and couple of sub folders under it

```
parent:
--subfolder1:
-----folderinsidesubfolder1:
-------file.tsv
--subfolder2:
-----folderinsidesubfolder2:
-------file.tsv
```

What I am trying to do is change the file.tsv with folder name one level above that is subfolder1,subfolder2 like this

```
parent:
    --subfolder1:
    -----folderinsidesubfolder1:
    -------subfolder1.tsv
    --subfolder2:
    -----folderinsidesubfolder2:
    -------subfolder2.tsv
```

Code:

```
from os import walk, path, rename
for dirpath, _, files in walk('pathto/parent'):
    for f in files:
        if f.endswith(".tsv"):
           print rename(f, dirpath[-2]+ '.tsv')
```

Error:

```
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Is this the right way to do it?

Comment: `dirpath` is just a string, you need to split it `os.path.split(dirpath)[-2]` but you aren't working in the file's directory, so you will need to `os.path.join()` the `pathto/parent` with `dirpath` + `new filename`.

Comment: @AChampion something like this? `(f, path.join(dirpath, (dirpath)[-2]+ '.tsv'))` ? I tried this still get same error `OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`os.path.split()` creates a head and tail, so you will need to split twice to get the grandparent directory, e.g.:

```
import os
for dirpath, _, files in os.walk('pathto/parent'):
    for f in files:
        if f.endswith('.tsv'):
            os.rename(os.path.join(dirpath, f), os.path.join(dirpath, os.path.split(os.path.split(dirpath)[0])[1] + '.tsv'))
```